# Lots of Failed: Template parse errors: Can't bind to 'routerLink' since it isn't a known property of 'a'. errors in Karma

Tags: angular, testing, karma-jasmine, karma-runner

```
Failed: Template parse errors:
Can't bind to 'routerLink' since it isn't a known property of 'a'. ("nd">
            <img width="25" src="../assets/images/app_logo.jpg">
            <a class="navbar-brand" [ERROR ->][routerLink]="['/avior/dashboard']">&nbsp;&nbsp;=== Application ===</a>
        </a>

"): ng:///DynamicTestModule/AppComponent.html@7:27
...
NullInjectorError: StaticInjectorError[AviorBackendService]: 
  NullInjectorError: No provider for AviorBackendService!
...
Failed: Unexpected pipe 'SearchPipe' imported by the module 'DynamicTestModule'. Please add a @NgModule annotation.
...
Expected undefined to be truthy.
```

The same error goes over and over again for every a anchor with [routerLink] inside of it...

I tried importing RouterModule into app.component.ts AND app.module.ts, but it does not seem to help. I also imported it into every .ts file where the routerLink is used but that didn't help either.

I tried importing `import { RouterTestingModule } from '@angular/router/testing';` in the spec.ts and that didn't help either but I think it's somewhere in the right way.

P.S I haven't changed the .spec.ts files with a single exception.

**UPDATE**

My dashboard component spec.ts:

```
import { async, ComponentFixture, TestBed } from '@angular/core/testing';

import { DashboardComponent } from './dashboard.component';

describe('DashboardComponent', () => {
  let component: DashboardComponent;
  let fixture: ComponentFixture<DashboardComponent>;

  beforeEach(async(() => {
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      declarations: [ DashboardComponent ]
    })
    .compileComponents();
  }));

  beforeEach(() => {
    fixture = TestBed.createComponent(DashboardComponent);
    component = fixture.componentInstance;
    fixture.detectChanges();
  });

  it('should create', () => {
    expect(component).toBeTruthy();
  });
});
```

My Login Component spec.ts:

```
import { async, ComponentFixture, TestBed } from '@angular/core/testing';

import { LoginComponent } from './login.component';

describe('LoginComponent', () => {
  let component: LoginComponent;
  let fixture: ComponentFixture<LoginComponent>;

  beforeEach(async(() => {
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      declarations: [ LoginComponent ]
    })
    .compileComponents();
  }));

  beforeEach(() => {
    fixture = TestBed.createComponent(LoginComponent);
    component = fixture.componentInstance;
    fixture.detectChanges();
  });

  it('should create', () => {
    expect(component).toBeTruthy();
  });
});
```

As you can see they're default tests.

At AppComponent.html@7:27 the problem was indeed nested a anchors:

```
<a class="navbar-brand">
            <img width="25" src="../assets/images/app_logo.jpg">
            <a class="navbar-brand" [routerLink]="['/avior/dashboard']">&nbsp;&nbsp;=== Application ===</a>
    </a>
```

I changed the outer a anchor to div, but the other errors still persist.

Comment: import the RouterModule in your App Module

Comment: @VasimHayat forgot to specify that I already did that. That does not solve the problem apparently

Comment: What matters is not what your app module imports. What matters is what the testing module in the failing unit test imports. (i.e. RouterTestingModule needs to be in the imports of the module description passed to TestBed.configureTestingModule())

Comment: @JBNizet so how do I fix it?

Comment: What is unclear in my previous comment? RouterTestingModule needs to be in the imports of the module description passed to TestBed.configureTestingModule()

Comment: @JBNizet I tried putting it in like this `beforeEach(async(() => {
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      declarations: [ DashboardComponent ],
      imports: [ RouterTestingModule ]
    })
    .compileComponents();
  }));`. I also of course imported it above. Is this what you were implying? It does not work.

Comment: Yes. But the error message shows that the test fails when compiling AppComponent.html. And the testing module configuration you just posted is apparently the one used in the test of DashboardComponent.

Comment: can you post the suspect html at `AppComponent.html@7:27`. I don't think nesting an <a> inside an <a> is valid html. And the structure you posted doesn't clearly indicate the structure.

Comment: Please post your complete test code in the question.

Comment: As @JBNizet said in their comment using the RouterTestingModule will get you passed this error:  `import { RouterTestingModule } from '@angular/router/testing';
...

 beforeEach(async(() => {
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      imports: [RouterTestingModule],
      declarations: [ LoginComponent ]
    })
    .compileComponents();
  }));`

Comment: @JayChase yes it was the solution for that specific problem, I just needed to specify the routes as well as my answer points out.

Answer (score 3):

The real `RouterLinkDirective` is quite complicated and entangled with other components and directives of the `RouterModule`. It requires challenging setup to mock and use in tests.

The `RouterLinkDirectiveStub` in this sample code replaces the real directive with an alternative version designed to validate the kind of anchor tag wiring seen in the `AppComponent template`(For example).

For more information, visit the [angular testing docs](https://angular.io/guide/testing#components-with-routerlink)

Comment: The documentation is quite unclear. Where do I import this `router-link-directive-stub.ts`? I can't seem to get it to work

Comment: Ohk let me fix that `router-link-directive-stub` in your updated code . @Munchkin

Comment: Didn't really solve my problem, but didn't want that bounty go to waste..

Answer (score 1):

For those interested the solution was the following - I needed to import RouterTestingModule (and also ReactiveFormsModule and HttpClientTestingModule) and in imports specify the routes like the following:

```
imports: [ ReactiveFormsModule, HttpClientTestingModule, RouterTestingModule.withRoutes(
        [{path: '', redirectTo: 'avior/login', pathMatch: 'full'},

        {path: 'avior', loadChildren: () => import('../avior.module').then(m => m.AviorModule)},
        {path: 'avior/*', redirectTo: '/avior'},

        {path: 'carinae', loadChildren: () => import('../../carinae/carinae.module').then(m => m.CarinaeModule)},
        {path: 'carinae/*', redirectTo: '/carinae'},

        {path: '**', redirectTo: '/avior/404'}]
      ) ],
```

For

```
NullInjectorError: StaticInjectorError[AviorBackendService]: 
  NullInjectorError: No provider for AviorBackendService!
```

I needed to declare the BackendService as a provider and also import HttpClientTestingModule.